# How to convert a list to string in a user queryset , i created a user with different.roles is displaying in a list format in user list

Tags: django-rest-framework

models.py

```
class Role(models.Model):
    '''
    The Role entries are managed by the system,
    automatically created via a Django data migration.
    '''
    Employee = 1
    Admin = 2
    Client = 3
    Reporter = 4
    authorizer = 5
    vet_doc = 6

    ROLE_CHOICES = (
        (Employee, 'Publisher'),
        (Admin, 'Admin'),
        (Client, 'Client'),
        (Reporter, 'Reporter'),
        (authorizer, 'authorizer'),
    )

    id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(primary_key=True,default=True,choices=ROLE_CHOICES)
    role=models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.get_id_display()
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerliazer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id','email', 'username', 'password','first_name','last_name','is_active','roles')
        extra_kwargs = {'password': {'write_only': True}}

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User(
            email=validated_data['email'],
            username=validated_data['username']
        )
        user.set_password(validated_data['password'])
        user.save()
        return user
```

views.py

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
@permission_classes((AllowAny,))
def User_list(request):
    '''
    list  all Breed and create a breed
    '''
    if request.method == 'GET':
        query_set = User.objects.all()
        serializer = UserSerliazer(query_set, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

output

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "email": "name@gmail.com",
    "username": "suresh2",
    "first_name": "first",
    "last_name": "last",
    "is_active": true,
    "roles": [
        2
    ]
},
```

I want to display  "roles":2 instead of "roles": [2]

Comment: With respect, shouldn't a a user be able to have multiple roles? They could be an `admin` and an `editor` or a `chef` and a `manager`.  Isn't a list the correct result?

Comment: yes, for one user there will be one role , so i want to display the role normally , not in a list as it's a single data.Is there a way to do it , any suggestions.